# using explode function in dataframe spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

```
df2.withColumn("cid", regexp_replace(df2("cid"), "\"", ""))

 trentyid | cid
----------+----------
 a        | 1, 5, 16
 b        | 76, 34
```

Both `trendyid` and `cid` are string columns.

```
df3.select($"trentyid".as("trentyid"), explode(split($"cid", ",")).as("cid1"))
```

Output:

```
 trentyid | cid1
----------+----------
 a        |
 b        |
```

This last line seems to not work as expected, as the second column is empty.

What could the cause of that be?

Comment: Your code `val df4=df3.select($"trentyid".as("trentyid"),explode(split( $"cid", ",")).as("cid1"))` is working as expected. It is giving correct result.

Comment: But why is that cid1 empty........i want cid1 to have all the values i.e 1,5,16 ,76,34 in separate rows .

Comment: It's not empty. I got following result - `+--------+----+
|trentyid|cid1|
+--------+----+
|a       |1   |
|a       |5   |
|a       |16  |
|b       |76  |
|b       |34  |
+--------+----+
`

Comment: Got the expected result myself. After three confirmations, you may want to check your code as there may be something else wrong with it.